When I switch to Tablet size or Mobile size,the button doesnot work how can i fix it?

<!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
  <ul class=" head navbar-nav ml-auto ">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
      </li>
  </ul>

I tried to change date-toggle and data-target but nothing changed
Bootstrap scripts for CSS and JS are Applied

In Bootstrap 5, make sure you have already imported the popper.min.js and bootstrap.min.js.
Example:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



Please check your bootstrap version , make sure you are using bootstrap version that support data-bs-toggle attribute .
Ensure Bootstrap and CSS  Included , Just double-check that you've included them properly in your HTML.
Viewport meta tag : This tag is necessary for proper scaling in mobile device.



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">




technical incorrect. The meta viewport tag is not necessary to scale properly. It just disables the DPR ability to make it easier for developers to test while reducing UX in exchange.
